# Data in a HashMap after closing an android application

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I use a HashMap in order to store some keys and it's values like the following.

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put(key, value);
```

How can it be possible to store the data from HashMap before closing my app and retrieve them when I open the application next time in order to be able to add a new entry to the already entries. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Serialization. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html

Comment: check this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html for storage options. use the one that suits you. retrieve when you need it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use serialization. It will write your data in a file on your hard drive and you will be able to load them when you relaunch the app.

Since you are using String as a key and as a value and since String implements Serializable it should be easy.

Here's how to write :

```
    File file = new File("nameOfYourFile");
    FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);
    ObjectOutputStream s = new ObjectOutputStream(f);
    s.writeObject(yourHashMap);
    s.close();
```

And to read :

```
    File file = new File("temp");
    FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream(file);
    ObjectInputStream s = new ObjectInputStream(f);
    HashMap<String, Object> fileObj2 = (HashMap<String, Object>) s.readObject();
    s.close();
```